# Where do I get the location of Elon Musk's private jet?

Tags: aviation

Given that he has banned the Twitter account that tracked his private jet, I wondered if anyone knew where the account got its data from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new microblogging account is on Mastodon:

https://mastodon.social/@elonjet

However, the data is and always has been coming from https://ADSBExchange.com

While free to see [on the website](https://globe.adsbexchange.com/), ADSBExchange's data is not actually strictly open in API nor download form:

> Commercial Usage Terms
>
> As noted in the legal terms and conditions, commercial (for profit or non-profit organization) use requires written authorization from ADS-B Exchange.  This is necessary to ensure operating this site remains financially viable and continues to provide unfiltered global tracking services.
>
> Commercial users are required to contact ADSBexchange for a commercial data license agreement. While our pricing is far less than other “big” providers, the technical infrastructure for running a site of this scale does require ongoing funds to support it.
>
> No bulk resale or redistribution is permitted without consent from ADSBexchange.com.
>
> Global low latency access is available with a commercial usage agreement.

Comment: There is also a sub Reddit that is doing this as well